# How many Thread would be created?

Tags: java

```
public class ThreadTest extends Thread
{
    int i=0;

    public void run()
    {
        i=1;
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        ThreadTest tTest=new ThreadTest();
        tTest.start();

        System.out.println(tTest.i);
    }
}
```

Why does this sometimes print 1 and sometimes print 0? How many thread would create in this program? As I understand, 2 thread would be created in this program. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Are you asking why this sometimes prints 1 and sometimes prints 0?

Comment: why this sometimes prints 1 and sometimes prints 0?

Answer (score 10):

You have a race condition.  Sometimes the main thread wins, sometimes the test thread wins.

There are 2 threads in the program, only one of which is instantiated by the program.  the main thread is created by the jvm and is executing the `main()` method.  your code then instantiates a test thread and executes it.

Comment: tTest.join() then it always print 1.am i right?

Comment: provided you put it before the System.out.println .....

Answer (score 3):

The program code starts one thread. The JVM itself starts several ones: the main thread, the GC thread, etc.

The output could be 0 or 1 because the `System.out.println` line might execute before or after the `i=1` line. You have absolutely no guarantee, since no synchronization is used. And since the shared `i` variable is accessed by two threads without any kind of synchronization, even if `i=1` is executed before the other instruction, the main thread could still see 0 as the value of `i`.

This is quite complex stuff, and you should read a good book about it if you really want to understand concurrency in Java, like *Java concurrency in Practice*, by Brian Goetz.

Comment: I knew the answer but I wanted to clear my doubt.

Answer (score 2):

Two application threads

- the "main" thread
- the one started by tTest.start()

I would guess that the program sometines prints 0 and sometimes prints 1 as a result of the scheduling of the threads. Sometiomes the main thread will reach the System.out.println statement before the tTest thread has entered the run method, sometimes it won't.